# Python setuptools: how to include a config file for distribution into <prefix>/etc

Tags: python, setuptools

How can I write `setup.py` so that:

1. The binary egg distribution (`bdist_egg`) includes a sample configuration file and
2. Upon installation puts it into the `{prefix}/etc` directory?

A sample project source directory looks like this:

```
bin/
   myapp
etc/
   myapp.cfg
myapp/
    __init__.py
    [...]
setup.py
```

The setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.command.install_data import install_data

packages = ['myapp', ]
scripts = ['bin/myapp',]
cmdclasses = {'install_data': install_data}
data_files = [('etc', ['etc/myapp.cfg'])]

setup_args = {
    'name': 'MyApp',
    'version': '0.1',
    'packages': packages,
    'cmdclass': cmdclasses,
    'data_files': data_files,
    'scripts': scripts,
#    'include_package_data': True,
    'test_suite': 'nose.collector'
}

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(**setup_args)
```

setuptools are installed in both the build environment and in the installation environment.

The `'include_package_data'` commented out or not does not help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was doing some research on this issue and I think the answer is in the setuptools documentation: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#non-package-data-files

Next, I quote the extract that I think has the answer:

> Non-Package Data Files
>
> The distutils normally install general "data files" to a
>   platform-specific location (e.g. /usr/share). This feature intended to
>   be used for things like documentation, **example configuration files**,
>   and the like.  setuptools does not install these data files in a
>   separate location, however. They are bundled inside the egg file or
>   directory, alongside the Python modules and packages. The data files
>   can also be accessed using the Resource Management API [...]
>
> Note, by the way, that this encapsulation of data files means that **you
>   can't actually install data files to some arbitrary location on a
>   user's machine**; this is a feature, not a bug. You can always include a
>   script in your distribution that extracts and copies your the
>   documentation or data files to a user-specified location, at their
>   discretion. If you put related data files in a single directory, you
>   can use resource_filename() with the directory name to get a
>   filesystem directory that then can be copied with the shutil module.
>   [...]

Comment: Why is it a feature, not a bug?

Comment: @Flimm , it is a feature because it is intended to work like that. The API has been specifically designed to present such behavior. It is even documented and properly explained.
A [bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) is an error, flaw, mistake, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces an incorrect or unexpected result, or causes it to behave in unintended ways.

Comment: I meant, why did they intend it to work that way? It seems to me like one would want to be able to install data files to arbitrary locations on a user's machine.

Comment: @Flimm The `resource_filename()` api provides increased flexibility for platforms that wouldn't let an application install its files to arbitrary locations. It also allows for packaging everything into a single egg file, with data files being decompressed on demand.

Comment: @Flimm We often view the inconveniences created by security measures to be bugs. We also view lack of security to be a bug. That said... As you can see from https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files that feature/bug has been eliminated. Congratulations, you can now replace a victims '/bin/bash' when they pip install your json library. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

##### Please note that the recommendations regarding config files *outside* the package have been updated since the question was originally asked.

PyPa now recommends that all configuration/python setup files for distribution be included **within** the package.

Please read here the relevant excerpt from the [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#non-package-data-files) (own highlights):

> **Non-Package Data Files**
> Historically, setuptools by way of easy_install would encapsulate data files from the distribution into the egg (see the old docs). As eggs are deprecated and pip-based installs fall back to the platform-specific location for installing data files, there is no supported facility to reliably retrieve these resources.
> **Instead, the PyPA recommends that any data files you wish to be accessible at run time be included inside the package.**